# how to fit UILabel in portrait and landscape and also vertical alignment?

Tags: ios, ios6, uilabel, autoresizingmask

i fix a UILabel in portrait as well as landscape by using

```
Label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

but not set in vertical alignment of UILabel ,i also try this

```
[Label sizeToFit];
```

Any way too do both of them are work

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use flexible height for fixing vertical alignment with OR operator

> Label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

**EDIT:**

> ```
> Label.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
> ```

Comment: i am trying them but it fill a whole area not vertically align

Comment: what do you mean by vertically align?

Comment: uilabel text not align at top

Comment: can you paste the screenshot what you are getting and what you expecting?